# Creating a New Location in my Database using Postman and getting a 400 error

Tags: database, mongodb, api, post, postman

Just getting familiar with Postman. Sending thru my first requests. Working out of the book gettingMean chapter6 section 6.4.2. Just created a controller called locationsCreate. Using postman i am supposed to send thru a post request to add a location to my database document. I should be getting back a location that was just created but instead getting a 400 code. My controller code in VSC looks good, no errors, the route is good, everything is connected. Where should I start tracking down this mistake?

[shows 400 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4loo.png)

[params set on postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8uaJ.png)

[params set on postman-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YA52x.png)

Comment: Please add your code and error

Comment: looks like your input is wrong, check your body and parameter again.. can you create a collection and share link.. ?